# Why React Parent not re-rendering when it's local state it's changed by children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have a parent component that has local state, and pass the setState function to the children.

The children sucessfully changes the parent local stage with the setState function, but the component does not re-render even after this state has change. If I make any change to the state in the parent component, I can see the rendering of both, the modifications made from the child (confirmin that it was actually modifying the local state), and the change made by the parent. But this re-renderin happens only when the change comes from the same component (the parent). I.e, there's no re-rendering if the change comes form any of the children.

Parent component:

```
const CustomizeItem = ({ item, i }) => {
  const [removed, setRemoved] = useState([]);
  const [added, setAdded] = useState([]);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(item.price);

  const handleRemovable = (removable) => {
    if (removed.indexOf(removable) === -1) {
      setRemoved([...removed, removable]);
    } else {
      let removedCopy = [...removed];
      removedCopy.splice(removed.indexOf(removable), 1);
      setRemoved(removedCopy);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(added);
    console.log(price);
  }, [added, price]);

  return (
    <div className="border-2 ">
      <p>
        Personaliza la {item.name} Nro {i + 1}:
      </p>
      <div>
        <p>Remover:</p>
        {item.removables.map((r, i) => {
          return (
            <label>
              {r.name}
              <input
                name={r.name}
                type="checkbox"
                checked={null}
                onChange={() => handleRemovable(r)}
              />
            </label>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <p>Añadir:</p>
        {item.extras.map((extra, i) => {
          return (
            <ExtraItem
              key={i + 1}
              extra={extra}
              added={added}
              setAdded={setAdded}
              removed={removed}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Resumen: </p>
        <div>
          {g(item, "Un", "Una", "s")} <strong>"{item.name}"</strong>
          {removed.length > 0 && (
            <p>
              {removed.map((r) => (
                <p>✖️ Sin {r.name}</p>
              ))}
            </p>
          )}
          {added.length > 0 && (
            <p>
              {added.map((a) => (
                <p>✔️ Con extra de {a.name}</p>
              ))}
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Precio: ${price}</p>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomizeItem;
```

Children:

```
const ExtraItem = ({ added, setAdded, extra }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const addExtra = (extra) => {
    let addedCopy = added;
    addedCopy.push(extra);
    setAdded(addedCopy);
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const removeExtra = (extra) => {
    let addedCopy = added;
    addedCopy.splice(addedCopy.indexOf(extra), 1);
    setAdded(addedCopy);
    setCount(count - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between">
      <p>
        {extra.name} - ${extra.price}
      </p>
      <div className="flex gap-2">
        <IconButton
          variant="outlined"
          color="red"
          className="flex-none"
          size="sm"
          onClick={() => removeExtra(extra)}
        >
          <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-minus" />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="h4" className="text-justify text-green-400">
          {count}
        </Typography>
        <IconButton
          variant="outlined"
          color="green"
          className="flex-none"
          onClick={() => addExtra(extra)}
          size="sm"
        >
          <i className="fas fa-plus" />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExtraItem;
```

Note that the useEffect with the dependency of added (in the parent) isn't triggered when the change comes from any of the children...

Comment: `array.push` is not creating a new array. React expect an `immutable` value. Try to create a new array with `[...array, addedValue]`

Comment: `let addedCopy = added;` is the problem, you'll want to create a new array with `let addedCopy = [...added];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try copying the array and then setting it to the state. Like this:

```
let addedCopy = [...added];
addedCopy.push(extra);
setAdded(addedCopy);
```

Comment: You're right. I wasn't creating a new array as I thought I was.